# How do I require a linked issue in a github pull request before allowing the PR to be merged/closed

Tags: github, pull-request, github-issues

Is there a way to force an issue to be linked to a PR before allowing the user to merge/close the PR? I was able to set up all of the other checks in the branch protection rule, but I cannot find a way to check that there is at least 1 linked issue.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no intrinsic way to require this.  However, you can use a CI check, such as a GitHub Action, to read the PR text from the API and require it to mention an open issue, which will prevent it from being merged without containing the expected text.

However, as for closing a pull request without merging it, such as if the submitted decides that the change is no longer necessary or should not have been made, it's not possible to prevent the user from doing so.  Such a policy wouldn't be helpful, since it would force users to leave unwanted pull requests open.

Comment: requested feature at https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/9706

Comment: Researching this I found this github action most useful for your use case https://github.com/nearform/github-action-check-linked-issues

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough starting point you could use for our own GitHub Action to require linked issues on PRs (save this as `.github/workflows/linked-issues.yml`, for example):

```yaml
name: Check Linked Issues
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, edited, synchronize]

jobs:
  check-linked-issues:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check for linked issues
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          QUERY='query ($prNumber: Int!, $repositoryName: String!, $repositoryOwner: String!) { 
            repository(name: $repositoryName, owner: $repositoryOwner) { 
              pullRequest(number: $prNumber) { 
                closingIssuesReferences(first: 10) { 
                  nodes { 
                    number 
                  } 
                } 
              } 
            } 
          }'
          
          ISSUES=$(gh api graphql -f query="$QUERY" -F prNumber=${{ github.event.pull_request.number }} -F repositoryName=${{ github.event.repository.name }} -F repositoryOwner=${{ github.event.repository.owner.login }} -q '.data.repository.pullRequest.closingIssuesReferences.nodes[] | .number')

          if [ -z "$ISSUES" ]
          then
            echo "No issues linked to this PR. Please link an issue and try again."
            exit 1
          else
            echo "Issue(s) linked: $ISSUES"
          fi
```

You won't find linked issues in the REST API, to my knowledge.

One thing that's important to note is that if you link issues from the PR sidebar instead of the PR description, it doesn't actually trigger any webhooks that you can use for CI, so it's not bulletproof. There are some specific examples of the two different ways to link issues here: https://www.pullapprove.com/docs/examples/verifying-linked-issues-for-traceability/